# Encoded characters in string preventing form from being submitted

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "post";
    form.action = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login?action=login";
    form.id = "loginForm";
```

I also have a button that `submits()` the `form` above, the problem is that that `submit()` launches the link by replacing brackets `{` and `}` with their ASCII code. In my browser this appears as:

```
"$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/login?action=login"
```

...instead of:

```
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login?action=login"
```

My questions:

- How do I force the browser to replace `%7B` and `%7D` with `{` and `}`, respectively?
- How can I make `submit()` launch the decoded link?

Comment: I think you want the action to be decoded before it's fired? Otherwise the URL is just the variable name.

Comment: You *literally* want the URL to be `http://example.com/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login?action=login` ?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "launches the link"?

Comment: `form.action = ${pageContext.request.contextPath}+"/login?action=login";` you may want something like this, where the variable is concatenated, not inside the quotes

Comment: Pretty sure this is supposed to be parsed server side...

Comment: For me the "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" parts does look like a variable within a backend template?!

Comment: I  guess you are looking for unescape(str)

Comment: @HaBo Probably not, if the intent is to actually submit the form. As others mentioned, `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` needs to be evaluated *before* this hits the clientside.

Comment: Is this JavaScript code in a `.js` file or within a JSP?

Comment: @Sterling Archer: exactly, I want the action to be decoded before it's fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was:

`"${pageContext.request.contextPath}"`

was interpreted literally because it was inside JavaScript file and not inside a variable from jsp. I declared a variable rootPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" and afterwards

```
"form.action = rootPath + "/login?action=login";"
```

Now everything works as desired.